# Django Routing caused Module not found error

Tags: python, django

While defining path from Django project (eitan) to Djnago app (users_and_auth) I get this below mentioned error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 406, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 587, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 580, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/app/eitan/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('users/', include('users_and_auth.urls')),
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users_and_auth.urls'
```

I first created a `urls.py` file in Django app (users_and_auth) folder as shown below.

**users_and_auth/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', views.UserAPIViews.as_view()),
]
```

Then I modified the project's url.py as stated below

**eitan/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [    
    path('users/', include('users_and_auth.urls')),
]
```

I have also declare `users_and_auth` in `settings.py` file under `installed apps`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'users_and_auth',
]
```

Root URL config is also defined as stated below.

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'eitan.urls'
```

The tree structure of directory is -

```
.
└── app
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── docker-compose.yaml
    ├── eitan
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── settings.pyc
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── urls.pyc
    │   ├── wsgi.py
    │   └── wsgi.pyc
    ├── manage.py
    ├── mysql
    │   ├── auto.cnf
    │   ├── eitan_database
    │   │   ├── auth_group.frm
    │   │   ├── auth_group.ibd
    │   │   ├── auth_group_permissions.frm
    │   │   ├── auth_group_permissions.ibd
    │   │   ├── auth_permission.frm
    │   │   ├── auth_permission.ibd
    │   │   ├── auth_user.frm
    │   │   ├── auth_user.ibd
    │   │   ├── auth_user_groups.frm
    │   │   ├── auth_user_groups.ibd
    │   │   ├── auth_user_user_permissions.frm
    │   │   ├── auth_user_user_permissions.ibd
    │   │   ├── db.opt
    │   │   ├── django_admin_log.frm
    │   │   ├── django_admin_log.ibd
    │   │   ├── django_content_type.frm
    │   │   ├── django_content_type.ibd
    │   │   ├── django_migrations.frm
    │   │   ├── django_migrations.ibd
    │   │   ├── django_session.frm
    │   │   └── django_session.ibd
    │   ├── ib_logfile0
    │   ├── ib_logfile1
    │   ├── ibdata1
    │   ├── mysql
    │   │   ├── columns_priv.MYD
    │   │   ├── columns_priv.MYI
    │   │   ├── columns_priv.frm
    │   │   ├── db.MYD
    │   │   ├── db.MYI
    │   │   ├── db.frm
    │   │   ├── event.MYD
    │   │   ├── event.MYI
    │   │   ├── event.frm
    │   │   ├── func.MYD
    │   │   ├── func.MYI
    │   │   ├── func.frm
    │   │   ├── general_log.CSM
    │   │   ├── general_log.CSV
    │   │   ├── general_log.frm
    │   │   ├── help_category.MYD
    │   │   ├── help_category.MYI
    │   │   ├── help_category.frm
    │   │   ├── help_keyword.MYD
    │   │   ├── help_keyword.MYI
    │   │   ├── help_keyword.frm
    │   │   ├── help_relation.MYD
    │   │   ├── help_relation.MYI
    │   │   ├── help_relation.frm
    │   │   ├── help_topic.MYD
    │   │   ├── help_topic.MYI
    │   │   ├── help_topic.frm
    │   │   ├── innodb_index_stats.frm
    │   │   ├── innodb_index_stats.ibd
    │   │   ├── innodb_table_stats.frm
    │   │   ├── innodb_table_stats.ibd
    │   │   ├── ndb_binlog_index.MYD
    │   │   ├── ndb_binlog_index.MYI
    │   │   ├── ndb_binlog_index.frm
    │   │   ├── plugin.MYD
    │   │   ├── plugin.MYI
    │   │   ├── plugin.frm
    │   │   ├── proc.MYD
    │   │   ├── proc.MYI
    │   │   ├── proc.frm
    │   │   ├── procs_priv.MYD
    │   │   ├── procs_priv.MYI
    │   │   ├── procs_priv.frm
    │   │   ├── proxies_priv.MYD
    │   │   ├── proxies_priv.MYI
    │   │   ├── proxies_priv.frm
    │   │   ├── servers.MYD
    │   │   ├── servers.MYI
    │   │   ├── servers.frm
    │   │   ├── slave_master_info.frm
    │   │   ├── slave_master_info.ibd
    │   │   ├── slave_relay_log_info.frm
    │   │   ├── slave_relay_log_info.ibd
    │   │   ├── slave_worker_info.frm
    │   │   ├── slave_worker_info.ibd
    │   │   ├── slow_log.CSM
    │   │   ├── slow_log.CSV
    │   │   ├── slow_log.frm
    │   │   ├── tables_priv.MYD
    │   │   ├── tables_priv.MYI
    │   │   ├── tables_priv.frm
    │   │   ├── time_zone.MYD
    │   │   ├── time_zone.MYI
    │   │   ├── time_zone.frm
    │   │   ├── time_zone_leap_second.MYD
    │   │   ├── time_zone_leap_second.MYI
    │   │   ├── time_zone_leap_second.frm
    │   │   ├── time_zone_name.MYD
    │   │   ├── time_zone_name.MYI
    │   │   ├── time_zone_name.frm
    │   │   ├── time_zone_transition.MYD
    │   │   ├── time_zone_transition.MYI
    │   │   ├── time_zone_transition.frm
    │   │   ├── time_zone_transition_type.MYD
    │   │   ├── time_zone_transition_type.MYI
    │   │   ├── time_zone_transition_type.frm
    │   │   ├── user.MYD
    │   │   ├── user.MYI
    │   │   └── user.frm
    │   ├── performance_schema
    │   │   ├── accounts.frm
    │   │   ├── cond_instances.frm
    │   │   ├── db.opt
    │   │   ├── events_stages_current.frm
    │   │   ├── events_stages_history.frm
    │   │   ├── events_stages_history_long.frm
    │   │   ├── events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_stages_summary_by_host_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_stages_summary_by_thread_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_stages_summary_by_user_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_stages_summary_global_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_statements_current.frm
    │   │   ├── events_statements_history.frm
    │   │   ├── events_statements_history_long.frm
    │   │   ├── events_statements_summary_by_account_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_statements_summary_by_digest.frm
    │   │   ├── events_statements_summary_by_host_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_statements_summary_by_thread_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_statements_summary_by_user_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_statements_summary_global_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_waits_current.frm
    │   │   ├── events_waits_history.frm
    │   │   ├── events_waits_history_long.frm
    │   │   ├── events_waits_summary_by_account_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_waits_summary_by_host_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_waits_summary_by_instance.frm
    │   │   ├── events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_waits_summary_by_user_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── file_instances.frm
    │   │   ├── file_summary_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── file_summary_by_instance.frm
    │   │   ├── host_cache.frm
    │   │   ├── hosts.frm
    │   │   ├── mutex_instances.frm
    │   │   ├── objects_summary_global_by_type.frm
    │   │   ├── performance_timers.frm
    │   │   ├── rwlock_instances.frm
    │   │   ├── session_account_connect_attrs.frm
    │   │   ├── session_connect_attrs.frm
    │   │   ├── setup_actors.frm
    │   │   ├── setup_consumers.frm
    │   │   ├── setup_instruments.frm
    │   │   ├── setup_objects.frm
    │   │   ├── setup_timers.frm
    │   │   ├── socket_instances.frm
    │   │   ├── socket_summary_by_event_name.frm
    │   │   ├── socket_summary_by_instance.frm
    │   │   ├── table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage.frm
    │   │   ├── table_io_waits_summary_by_table.frm
    │   │   ├── table_lock_waits_summary_by_table.frm
    │   │   ├── threads.frm
    │   │   └── users.frm
    │   └── root
    │       └── db.opt
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── users_and_auth
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── admin.py
        ├── apps.py
        ├── managers.py
        ├── migrations
        │   └── __init__.py
        ├── models.py
        ├── serializers.py
        ├── tests.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── views.py
```

What could have possible caused this problem.

Comment: did you add the app in settings.py?

Comment: yes i did add the app in settings.py under installed apps.

Comment: You seem to be using Docker. Are you sure your Docker setup correctly mounts all of your `/app`, so the module can actually be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you tried to set URL as below...

```
urlpatterns = [    
    path('users/', include('<project_name>.<app_name>.<urls>')),
]
```

In your case...

```
urlpatterns = [    
    path('users/', include('project_name.users_and_auth.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Comment: You can also upvote the answer, it will help a lot to me, Thanks.